# How can I start a web browser and open a certain web page from Erlang on Windows in IE?

Tags: erlang

I have an erlang program which runs a server on a local machine and I would like it to start a local web browser and point to itself on startup. How can I do this in a portable way across Windows XP. Vista, and Windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use the following code on windows systems:

```
URL = "http://www.google.com/", os:cmd("start " ++ URL).
```

This has two advantages:

1) No need for the right path of the
    browser.
2) Works even if someone doesn't use
    IE.


Too bad I don't know of something similar on Linux or MacOS.

Comment: bsmr: have a look at the Python source code for the browser module to understand how to achieve the same on Linux and other os for that matter.

Comment: For macos replace "start" with "open" and you get the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

`URL = "http://www.google.com", os:cmd("\"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe\"" ++ URL).`

You might have to modify the path if IE isn't located in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the port api in erlang to start a normal command.

For open a browser you have multiple options:

- Look to the IExplorer.exe or how its called and start it with the URL as a parameter
- Use the rundll32.exe command to open a browser through the windows api. I guess this will use the configured browser, so this is recommended.